# jQuery Unslider working locally, but not on server

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im having a strange problem when trying to implement jQuery Unslider on a website. I get everything working like a charm locally, but when I upload it to my host (One.com in this case), it all falls apart. The images in the slideshow now appear below one another.

I have looked for issues with the code for so long now my eyes are turning inwards. So, please help me if you can =)

Link to test site: http://villabalder.se/VBv2/index.html

Scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/unslider.js"></script>
```

jQuery:

```
    $(function() {
    $('.vbslides').unslider({
        speed: 500,               //  The speed to animate each slide (in milliseconds)
        delay: 3000,              //  The delay between slide animations (in milliseconds)
        complete: function() {},  //  A function that gets called after every slide animation
        keys: true,               //  Enable keyboard (left, right) arrow shortcuts
        dots: true,               //  Display dot navigation
        fluid: false              //  Support responsive design. May break non-responsive designs
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="vbslides">
<ul>
    <li><img src="img/villabalder_ext1.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="img/villabalder_ext2.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="img/villabalder_int1.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="img/villabalder_int2.jpg"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .vbslides { 
    position: relative; 
    overflow: no; 
}

.vbslides ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.vbslides ul li {  
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    .vbslides .dot {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
    -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
    -ms-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
    -o-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
    filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
}

.vbslides .dots {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 20px;
}

    .vbslides .dots li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        margin: 0 4px;

        text-indent: -999em;

        border: 2px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 6px;

        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: .4;

        -webkit-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
        -moz-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
        transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
    }

        .vbslides .dots li.active {
            background: #fff;
            opacity: 1;
        }
```

Comment: You have a few errors in Console ..  Particularly it can't find :  `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://villabalder.se/VBv2/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"`   and   `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://villabalder.se/VBv2/js/modernizr.custom.36240.js"`  I am assuming this is breaking your jQuery ..    On a side note Console is a tool that will increase your trouble shooting time immeasurably .. It's worth the time to learn to use properly ..

Answer (score 0):

so you're calling the following in your head element:

```
<!-- Övriga jQuery filer -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/unslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker-sv.js"></script>
```

and then at the end of your body, you're calling these:

```
<!-- Hämtar Google CDN jQuery, med lokal back-up -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker-sv.js"></script>
```

which is overwriting the $ variable, and your unslider plugin is no longer defined.

Just to be clear: you should only have one core jQuery library being loaded, and it should (usually) be the first script file you are loading on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve problem using online files:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="http://unslider.com/unslider.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Be sure that JavaScript looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
$('.banner').unslider({
    speed: 500,               //  The speed to animate each slide (in milliseconds)
    delay: 3000,              //  The delay between slide animations (in milliseconds)
    complete: function() {},  //  A function that gets called after every slide animation
    keys: true,               //  Enable keyboard (left, right) arrow shortcuts
    dots: true,               //  Display dot navigation
    fluid: false              //  Support responsive design. May break non-responsive designs

});
var unslider = $('.banner').unslider();

  $('.prev').click(function() {
      unslider.data('unslider').prev();
  });

  $('.next').click(function() {
      unslider.data('unslider').next();
  });
  return false;
});
</script>
```

If u still have problem copy/paste this example to the .html file

```
    <!-- The HTML -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

    <head>
    <title>Unslider.com arrow example</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="http://unslider.com/unslider.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- JavaScript -->

    <script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
$('.banner').unslider({
    speed: 500,               //  The speed to animate each slide (in milliseconds)
    delay: 3000,              //  The delay between slide animations (in milliseconds)
    complete: function() {},  //  A function that gets called after every slide animation
    keys: true,               //  Enable keyboard (left, right) arrow shortcuts
    dots: true,               //  Display dot navigation
    fluid: false              //  Support responsive design. May break non-responsive designs

});
var unslider = $('.banner').unslider();

  $('.prev').click(function() {
      unslider.data('unslider').prev();
  });

  $('.next').click(function() {
      unslider.data('unslider').next();
  });
  return false;
});
</script>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <style type="text/css">

* { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.banner {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
top: 50px;
/*z-index: -1;*/

font-size: 18px;
line-height: 24px;
text-align: center;

color: #FFFFFF;
text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);

background: #FFFFFF;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}
.banner ul {
list-style: none;
width: 300%;
}
.banner ul li {
display: block;
float: left;

min-height: 500px;

-o-background-size: 100% 100%;
-ms-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;

box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.banner .inner {
padding: 360px 0 110px;

float: left;
vertical-align:-100px;
}

.banner h1, .banner h2 {

font-size: 40px;
line-height: 52px;
color: #fff;
}

.banner .btn {
display: inline-block;
margin: 25px 0 0;
padding: 9px 22px 7px;
clear: both;

color: #fff;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
border : rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) solid 2px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
.banner .btn:hover {
background : rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}
.banner .btn:active {
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
-moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
-ms-filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
-o-filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
}

.banner .btn, .banner .dot {
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
-moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
-ms-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
-o-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
}

.banner .dots {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 20px;
width: 100%;
}
.banner .dots li {
display: inline-block;

width: 10px;
height: 10px;
line-height: 10px;
margin: 0 4px;

text-indent: -999em;


border: 2px solid #fff;
border-radius: 6px;

cursor: pointer;
opacity: .4;

-webkit-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
-moz-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
}
.banner .dots li.active {
background: #fff;
opacity: 1;
}




.unslider-arrow {
  font-family: Expressway;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3d3d3d;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  padding: 0 20px 5px 20px;
}

.next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  right: 0  
}

.prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  right: 90 /* change to left:0; if u wanna have arrow on left side */ 
}
</style>
     </head>
    <!-- Body of HTML document -->

    <body>
        <div class="slider">
        <div class="banner">
          <ul>
            <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/" alt="pixel" width="100%" /></li> 
            <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/" alt="pixel" width="100%" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/" alt="pixel" width="100%" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/" alt="pixel" width="100%" /></li>
         </ul>
        </div>
          <a href="#" class="unslider-arrow prev">&larr;</a>
          <a href="#" class="unslider-arrow next">&rarr;</a>
        </div>
   </body>  

</html>
```